# jQuery Roadmap - Cannot determine event using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using [jQuery Roadmap](https://github.com/stefanomarra/jquery-roadmap) in my project and I need to fetch the events from the database. I have a SQL statement that can fetch the date and content I want but I am facing some errors that I don't understand. This is my code:

php

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $date = $row["date"];
    $status = $row["status"];
                
    echo "<script>
    var events = [  
        {
            date: $date,
            content: $status
        }
    ];</script>";
}
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            
            $('#my-roadmap').roadmap(events, {
                eventsPerSlide: 4,
                slide: 1,
                prevArrow: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                nextArrow: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed server side, JS in the browser. What you're trying to do won't work. You need to get the results of `mysqli_fetch_array()` and return the array in a response to an ajax call, for example.

Your code would be factored into something like:

```
$events = [];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $events[] = [
       'date' => $row["date"],
       'content' => $row["status"]
    ];
}

return $events;
```

Note the `fetch` call being made in the javascript now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        fetch('/somewhere')
          .then(r => r.json())
          .then(events => {
            $('#my-roadmap').roadmap(events, {
              eventsPerSlide: 4,
              slide: 1,
              prevArrow: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
              nextArrow: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
            });
          });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. At least now I know where to start now.

Comment: I roughly modified your code to show you how it would be done.

Comment: Thanks @ded, what do I put in the fetch() function? The URL of the current page? And what exactly it does?

Comment: `/somewhere'` is the path to your api. `fetch` is a browser native http client for making requests.